# Power BI User Input Parameters?

Tags: powerbi

Is there a way for me to provide input parameters that are adjustable by the user at run time for PowerBI reports?   I have a graph that shows employee data by hour, but I want the user to be able to choose different employees.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a dropdown slicer from your employee dimension. The user can select an employee from there.

Steps:

1. Drag a slicer to the report (next to table visual)
2. Add employee name
3. In the right top corner you can choose dropdown.

Please be sure you have a star schema

Another option is that you allow the user to search in the filter, if you have many employees.